# Creating 100 threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to learn about multithreading in C++. I'm trying to create 100 threads with a loop by using an array of threads but I am getting an error. It gives this error:

```
error: array initializer must be an initializer list
thread threads[i](task1, list[i]);
```

Here is the code:

```
static int list [100] = {};
thread threads [100] = {};


void task1(int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    n = n + 1;
}

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list); i++){
    thread threads[i](task1, list[i]);
    threads[i].join();
  }

  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list); i++)
    total += list[i];

  cout << total << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using threads while trying to learn a new language. You should have a firm understanding of the basics before starting to work with threads.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading [the documentation for `std::thread::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join). You'll see the problem about two lines in.

Comment: Error aside, you'll be doing all the work sequentially, since you're dispatching every thread and _immediately_ blocking until it finishes with `join` before dispatching the next thread. Typically, to dispatch a batch of threads, you would dispatch each one in a single loop, and then `join` each thread in as _separate_ loop.

Comment: Threads are an advanced topic. Spend a few years learning C++ basics first, before playing with threads.

Comment: `thread threads[i](task1, list[i]);` makes no sense. Are you declaring a local `thread` or are you assigning to `thread[i]`?

Comment: Note that [`sizeof(list)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof#Example) probably doesn't give the result you expect.  You'd be better off using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) rather than traditional arrays.

Comment: But if you are compiling to C++17, using `std::size` in the place of `sizeof` will give the expected result.

Comment: Remember, there is an overhead in creating and maintaining threads.  Many programs may run faster without the threads or by minimizing the quantity of threads.  There is no guarantee that threads will be dispatched to different cores; worst case, they are scheduled on the same core & processor that your `main` function is running.

Answer (score 4):

You should do this differently. A thread must be initialized with the task it will be run and the arguments. When you create an array of 100 threads like that, it initializes them all with nothing, which is sort of a useless waste. Also, your use of `sizeof` is wrong. `sizeof` will give you the raw size of a data structure in bytes and will not give you the number of elements of an array. If you want to use `sizeof` to get the number of elements of an array you should do something like `sizeof(array) / sizeof(<element type>)`, in your case that would be `sizeof(list) / sizeof(int)`. But, really, you probably shouldn't be using C-style arrays in C++, and most certainly not in this case.

You should be building up a `vector` at run-time and using `emplace_back` to create the threads one by one. Also, you are writing your code in a very C-ish way. You should be writing C++, not C. (Also, a pet peeve, always prefer prefix `++`. It doesn't matter much here, but, sometimes it matters a LOT for performance reasons, and if you're in the habit of always using the prefix version, you won't have a problem.) Here is how this might look:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using ::std::thread;
using ::std::array;
using ::std::vector;
using ::std::cout;
using ::std::endl;
using ::std::ref;

static array<int, 100> list {};
vector<thread> threads;

void task1(int &n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    n = n + 1;
}

int main()
{
  threads.reserve(list.size());  // Not needed, an optimization.
  for (int &n : list) {  // Use a range-based for loop, not an explicit counting loop
      threads.emplace_back(task1, ::std::ref(n));
  }
  for (auto &thr : threads) {
      thr.join();
  }

  int total = 0;
  for (int const &n : list) {
    total += n;
  }    
  cout << total << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now, since this is a toy program, I'm not going to criticize your decision to just randomly create 100 threads. In reality, this is a bad idea. You want to tailor the number of threads you create to the number of CPUs you have or the OS is going to waste a bunch of time switching between busy threads. Limit threads in this way will involving using functions like `::std::thread::hardware_concurrency` to query how many cores are available and using that information to make your decision on how many threads to have at runtime.

This is not always the most simple way to write your program of course, and for simplicity's sake you may just choose an arbitrary number of threads and stick with it. But if you do that, it should be as small a number as you can get away with.

But, your cavalier approach to creating threads, and the way you `join`ed with each thread right after creating it tell me that you don't really understand exactly what threads do. If you `join` with a thread immediately, the thread isn't running concurrently. You're starting it up, then immediately waiting for it to finish before starting the next one.

Also, the tiny task you're having a thread do is a poor use of them. Threads are somewhat expensive to create. A function call that involves creating a thread each time you call it has tens, hundreds, or even thousands of microseconds of overhead. That doesn't sound like a lot of time, but you have to keep in mind that the typical function call overhead is something like 1/50th of a microsecond or even 1/100th of a microsecond. So, calling a function by creating a thread has tens of thousands of times as much overhead as calling a function normally.

This means that you should be doing reasonably large tasks in a thread. If the task doesn't take at least a millisecond of time, you shouldn't be creating a thread. And ideally, you should create a thread and then use a thread-safe queue to send it stuff to do. That will have a lot less overhead per-thing. Since the overhead for that is much smaller, you can then economically perform smaller tasks in a thread.

All of this is a lot to take in when you're just experimenting with a little program to create threads. But, badly written multi-threaded programs are a terrible thing to inflict on the world, and most especially on yourself. Beyond learning the basics of the thread interface, you should understand them thoroughly before you use them. They are a tool that is very easy to misuse.

Answer (score 4):

Your array `thread threads [100] = {};` creates 100 default initialized inactive threads.

You can replace these default threads by changing your loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list); i++){
    threads[i] = thread(task1, list[i]);    // <---- valid syntax
    threads[i].join();
}
```

This being said:

- it's a pitty to launch the thread and immediately join it.  Better have a second loop for joining if you expect some real multithreading.
- it's a better practice to use a `vector<thread>` so that you construct the threads only when you need them (see other answer)
- you may be interested in [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) to find out a hint about the number of really concurrent threads supported by your hardware, in order not to create too many threads and loose performance in too many context switches.

Answer (score 2):

Having as many threads running as you have problems to solve will probably cause your program to context switch a lot, and for that reason not solve it as fast as is possible. You usually don't want more threads running than what it supported by your hardware (and often one less).

Another thing that often makes a world of difference is [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) that can degrade your performance **a lot**.

If you are using a compiler supporting the new C++17 execution policies (like VS2017 or g++ 9) you can do a `for_each` loop using the parallel execution policy, `std::execution::par`, to do your work.

The below example (where I've increased the workload a lot) takes 3.2 seconds on my computer when I've made reasonably sure to avoid false sharing (using [alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size)) and 21.3 seconds using the default alignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array> // std::array
#include <execution> // std::execution::par
#include <new> // std::hardware_destructive_interference_size

struct bork {
    alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) int n;
    // int n; // default alignment
};

std::array<bork, 1000> list{ 0 };

int main() {
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, list.begin(), list.end(), [](auto& b) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) b.n = b.n + 1;
        }
    );

    long long total = 0;
    for (const auto& b : list) total += b.n;

    std::cout << total << "\n";
}
```